# Working with .txt in VS2008 in C

Tags: c, file, visual-studio-2008, text

I wrote some program which overwrites some text in .txt file and put the overwritten one in another output.txt... But it's constantly saying that the file can't be opened. What should I do?

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
 FILE *ul=fopen("hexbr.txt","r"),*iz=fopen("bitovi.txt","w");
 int i;
 char ch;

 if ((!ul)||(!iz)) { printf("Neuspesno otvaranje datoteke!");return 0; }
 while((ch=fgetc(ul))!=EOF)
  {
   if ((isdigit(ch)) || (c>='A' && c<='F'))
    {
     if (isalpha(ch))
       switch(ch)
       {
         case 'A': { fputc('1',iz);fputc('0',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('0',iz);continue; }
         case 'B': { fputc('1',iz);fputc('0',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);continue; }
         case 'C': { fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('0',iz);fputc('0',iz);continue; }
         case 'D': { fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('0',iz);fputc('1',iz);continue; }
         case 'E': { fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('0',iz);continue; }
         case 'F': { fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);fputc('1',iz);continue; }
       }
     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
       fputc((ch & 0X8)?'1':'0',iz);
       ch<<=1;
      }
    }
   else fputc(ch,iz);
   if (ch=='\n') { ch=fgetc(ul);fputc(ch,iz); }
  }
 fclose(ul);
 fclose(iz);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that attempts to open the file.

Comment: simple. remove _`some`_ code, modify _`some`_ other and don't forget to add _`some`_ more. :-)

Comment: the program compiles without error. The main problem is that I don't know where to put those notepad files i created... I've put them in folder where my project is, but it still won't open. Then I've put them in Debug folder(a subfolder of project folder). Then I included them in the project.. Nothing works with my files

Comment: @DinoDjakovac Please don't put code on comments; it's nearly impossible to read. Edit your question and add code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program did not compile without error, there is a pair of typos here, `c` should be `ch`:

```
... (c>='A' && c<='F') ...
```

Apart from that the program *almost* works, and the output file (created in the same folder as the executable) is readable.

There is a mistake in trying to handle `newline` chars, which mistakenly causes the next (printing) char to be passed through and not converted to binary. I left `newline` and `return` to be passed through like other non-hex chars.

Other than that, the handling of `A..F` is clumsy. I suggest trapping them like this:

```
while((ch=fgetc(ul))!=EOF)
{
    if ((isdigit(ch)) || (ch>='A' && ch<='F'))
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
            ch -= 7;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
            fputc((ch & 0X8)?'1':'0',iz);
            ch<<=1;
            }
    }
    else fputc(ch,iz);
}
```

And you might want to check and convert the lower case `a..f` too.

Comment: I already changed the c to ch, it still won't work. I put file where my project is, aswell... and cmdprmt still says CAN'T OPEN FILE :/

Comment: Hopefully you have changed the current directory in your command prompt to the project directory. Can you at least see the file with `dir bitovi.txt`?

Comment: I don't understand... you see, im pretty much new to this... so i know nothing